# how to stop my custom devise user update action from going through the registrations controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, controller

I have a simple admin page for approving new users by clicking a single link.

in views/users/index.html.erb

```
<%= link_to "Approve User", user_path(:id => user.id, "user[approved]" => true), :remote => true, :method => :patch %>
```

in users_controller.rb

```
def update
  @user = User.find(params[:id])

  if @user.update(user_params)
    redirect_to users_path
  else
    logger.debug "ADMIN UPDATE OF USER DID NOT WORK"
  end
end
```

in routes.rb

```
devise_for :users, :controllers => {:registrations => 'users/registrations', :sessions => 'users/sessions'}

resources :users, only: [:index, :show, :update]
```

This link works, i.e. the user is updated to approved. But after the action goes through the users controller, it also goes through the registrations controller..

```
Started PATCH "/users/6?user%5Bapproved%5D=true" for ::1 at 2015-05-02 21:27:34 -0700
Processing by UsersController#update as JS
  Parameters: {"user"=>{"approved"=>"true"}, "id"=>"6"}
  User Load (1.4ms)  SELECT  "t_customer".* FROM "t_customer" WHERE "t_customer"."cust_id" = $1  ORDER BY "t_customer"."cust_id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["cust_id", 2]]
  User Load (0.8ms)  SELECT  "t_customer".* FROM "t_customer" WHERE "t_customer"."cust_id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["cust_id", 6]]
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
  SQL (0.6ms)  UPDATE "t_customer" SET "approved" = $1, "updated_at" = $2 WHERE "t_customer"."cust_id" = $3  [["approved", "t"], ["updated_at", "2015-05-03 04:27:34.933469"], ["cust_id", 6]]
   (2.0ms)  COMMIT
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/users
Completed 302 Found in 21ms (ActiveRecord: 5.0ms)

Started PATCH "/users" for ::1 at 2015-05-02 21:27:34 -0700
Processing by Users::RegistrationsController#update as JS
  User Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  "t_customer".* FROM "t_customer" WHERE "t_customer"."cust_id" = $1  ORDER BY "t_customer"."cust_id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["cust_id", 2]]
...
```

How do I stop it from going through the registrations controller? I feel like I have to restrict it somehow in routes.rb, but I don't know how.

The reason I caught this error is because when the user clicks the "approve user" link, the users index page does not properly refresh indicating that the user is now approved. If I refresh it via the browser, then the change is indicated. I need the change to show up with the redirect_to call in the users controller. Will this happen once the registrations controller is cut out of the process?

Answer (score 1):

I removed :remote => true from my link_to's and it's no longer going through the registrations controller and the update is appearing on page refresh.

Comment: Did this work for you?  I get `ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError` when I use your solution and it shows a rollback in logs.  I think Devise overrides the ability to hit the update method in the `User` controller.  You didn't have this problem?